# MDX combine two measures with different timelines on one timeline

Tags: date, time, mdx

I have two measures `Time_Quantity` and `Time2_Quality`. These measures refer to two different timelines, `Time` and `Time2`. But as an output I want to have a query which shows me the two measures on one single timeline. I guess I have to combine the time and time2 timeline, but how? This is what i have so far:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Time_Quantity] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Quantity]
     ,[Measures].[Time-Quantity]
     ,[Time Dates].[Time Year-Quarter-Month-Date]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Time2_Quality] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Quality]
     ,[Measures].[Time2-Quantity]
     ,[Time2 Dates].[Time2 Year-Quarter-Month-Date]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    Time_Quantity
   ,Time2_Quality
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Timeline ON ROWS // **<<how to combine Time and Time2 Timeline in one single Timeline?**
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: why do you have `[Time Dates].[Time Year-Quarter-Month-Date]` and `[Time2 Dates].[Time2 Year-Quarter-Month-Date]` ?

Comment: Hi. Time is the date, where for example the order is placed and time2 shows when it was shipped.

Comment: @EsraYesil so you want one row to say July 2015 and the number of orders in July 2015 and the number of shipments in July 2015?

Comment: Yes. The measures should be shown on one row to see, when order was placed and when the shipment was done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like below. It might need extra development because it took 13sec.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[link_sales] AS 
     (LinkMember([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, [Ship Date].[Calendar]),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
     MEMBER [Measures].[link_tax] AS 
     (LinkMember([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, [Ship Date].[Calendar]),[Measures].[Internet Tax Amount])
 SELECT   
    {[Measures].[link_sales],[Measures].[link_tax]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY [Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS ON ROWS
 FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Result (time: 13sec)

```
              link_sales    link_tax
All Periods 29358677.2207   2348694.2301
CY 2005     3105587.3292    248446.991
H2 CY 2005  3105587.3292    248446.991
Q3 CY 2005  1349136.7362    107930.9407
July 2005   349490.1938 27959.2159
```